# How do I get rid of the unknown property name errors in Visual Studio?

Tags: css, visual-studio

When using jQuery UI and ThemeRoller the CSS files created contain several CSS properties that are not known by Visual Studio, such as `zoom` and `opacity`.  How can I keep these from showing up as errors in the error list when the CSS file is open in the editor pane?

In the spirit of SO, I'll add the solution I found as a response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> CSS --> CSS Specific (or Validation) and uncheck the `Detect unknown properties` checkbox.